# Remove embedded document from MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am trying to build a query that deletes an embedded document from a MongoDB document in PHP. What I have now is:

```
$collection->update(array("_id" => new MongoId($id)),
        array('$unset' => 'BUSCO.short_summary_data'));
```

I have also tried:

```
$collection->remove(array("_id" => new MongoId($id)),
        array('$unset' => 'BUSCO.short_summary_data'));
```

No error is thrown, but the embedded document still exists! Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current statement written in JSON looks like this:

```
{ $unset: 'BUSCO.short_summary_data' }
```

But according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/unset/):

> The $unset operator deletes a particular field. Consider the following
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> { $unset: { <field1>: "", ... } }
> ```
>
> The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.

So `$unset` expects an array with key-value pairs. Try:

```
$collection->update(array("_id" => new MongoId($id)),
        array('$unset' => array('BUSCO.short_summary_data' => '')));
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :-)